# Can't access data in an object within a Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I don't understand why I can't access the data inside the `user` object.

```
{
  "channel_id": 2,
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Clyde Santiago",
    "email": "dexterdev02@gmail.com",
    "created_at": "2017-07-25 08:10:58",
    "updated_at": "2017-07-25 08:10:58"
  },
  "message": "ssd"
}
```

Accessing the `channel_id`, `user`, `message` is fine. But when I access the data in the `user` it shows the error,

> "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Here's the HTML in my Vue component

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" v-for="conversation in conversations">
    <p>
      {{conversation.message}}
    </p>
    <small>{{conversation.user.name}}</small> // error here
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What error and is this data retrieved asynchronously?

Comment: Which data are you trying to access? {{conversation.user}} is an object so it should give [object Object]. {{conversation.user.id}} would give the user id etc

Comment: "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" Thats the error. I am using pusher

Comment: When i access {{conversation.user}} it is fine. But when I access the {{conversation.user.name}} it shows error  
"Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Comment: That doesn't mean `name` is undefined. It means `user` is.

Comment: Please edit the error in the question description itself.

Comment: Maybe you add the user to the object after you pass the object to the template. Could you show the part where add the user, where you pass the data to the object and where you do the logging of the content of the object.

Comment: @EmileBergeron You removed a critical part of the code in one of your edits.

Comment: @BertEvans Someone edited at the same time, my initial edit included the whole code OP provided.

Comment: @Clyde I meant for you to include the error message you were getting, not just the line of code.

Comment: @EmileBergeron You edited, OP edited in a key piece, then you overwrote it. OP has added it back in now.

Comment: @BertEvans Yes, the rollback dismissed that line, but **it wasn't relevant until OP said in the comments the error message he was getting**. I admit I didn't notice, the rollback was to get my improvements back into the question, which got lost because our edits were close in time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When data is retrieved asynchronously, it is not *immediately* defined. Because you are referencing

```
conversation.user.name
```

in the template, there are times when `user` is not defined, which results in your error.

Typically this is easily avoided with a guard.

```
{{conversation.user && conversation.user.name}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever templating language you are using is likely expecting a string when you call `{{conversation.user}}` but you are giving it an object. So when the template engine tries to echo out the "string" you pass to it, but it will not be a string when just targeting `conversation.user`..Hence the error

Try this instead `{{conversation.user.name}}`

If the information is being loaded in asynchronous you may need to check that the `user` object exist first. So to do that it would be something like:

`{{conversation.user && conversation.user.name}}`
or for something like handlebars it would be like this

```
{{#if conversation.user}}
    {{conversation.user.name}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: That's the error. accessing the {{conversation.user}} is fine. But when {{conversation.user.name}} it shows error  
"Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Comment: is it loaded asynchronous?

Comment: I upvoated it. I think it's correct. It's similar on the approved answer

Comment: I downvoted because the initial answer was not correct. You've since corrected it. This question is tagged with Vue and handlebars is irrelevant.

Answer (score -3):

As shown here, user is itself an object and not a printable value. Have you tried accessing its properties individually, like `{{conversation.user.name}}`?

Comment: N00b not getting this: My answer is downvoted because it answered the original question, which has since been heavily edited? What is the value of downvoting, then?

Comment: The question was _heavily_ (which is not what I would call heavily) edited because it wasn't clear. When answering an unclear question, you risk having the right answer to the wrong problem.